# webm not playing on Android

Tags: android

I was under the impression that webm played on Android, but I can't get the videos to play on my Galaxy Nexus.  I haven't tried in the browser on the phone, just straight up and in the VideoView.  Is there some magic combo of settings needed?

Comment: did you try other formats?

Comment: @njzk2 This is super old (in mobile years).  I'm pretty sure this would be fine now ;)

Comment: I don't know how I got here, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, webm plays on android just fine. However, know that HTML5 video is always tricky.

The best way to check is to simply load a webm file in your browser:
http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.webm

There a number of reasons why the video may not be playing for you including:

- The webm file may not have been encoded correctly
- You are using a video playing application that does not handle webm
  files
- Data integrity was lost when transferring it to your phone
- There may be an issue with the current build of your OS (although if
  you are 2.2 or later there really shouldn't be)

Play around with an html5 video generator to see which video formats are playing on your phone (webm and mp4 should) http://sandbox.thewikies.com/vfe-generator/

Comment: Build is ICS, 4.0.4, on the Galaxy Nexus.  I'm writing an application and trying to get the video to play in the VideoView.  I tried opening the app up from a file manager directly on the phone and that didn't work either.  I could try pulling the video from the phone back onto my computer to verify that its valid, but it was 2 separate videos, and the sizes look correct, so I'd be pretty surprised if they were corrupted. They do play fine on my computer.

Comment: Just tried the 'big_buck_bunny.webm' video and that didn't work either, directly anyway.  Haven't tried browser, but that's not really the problem I'm trying to solve. Browser wouldn't help.

Comment: Put some code Kevin, we are so blind right now without code.

Comment: @BenEggett: thank you for your link. My webm video does not works but your works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I did run in the same bug/problem while developing on my nexus4 (on huawei y300 and y303 phone it worked fine!). Switching to NuPlayer in the developer options fixed this. Apparently the deprecated AwesomePlayer can't play webm in my case.

Nexus 4 Android version 5.1

It's also talked about here: https://github.com/Floens/Clover/issues/2

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the deprecated awesomeplayer. This was enabled on my device for some reason, and disabling it (thus switching to nuplayer, the default) fixed many videos that didn't play! It's not an option to enable NuPlayer as mentioned in that link, but to disable AwesomePlayer.